# The "--" operator for list subtraction in Scala

Tags: list, scala

In "[S-99: Ninety-Nine Scala Problems](http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/)" they use `--` on a `List` in graph's `equals` method. The problem is, that in Scala I use (2.10.2), the `--` operator isn't present (or I'm missing some import).

```
scala> List(1) -- List(1)
<console>:8: error: value -- is not a member of List[Int]
              List(1) -- List(1)
                      ^
```

Expected result is empty list.

In older versions of Scala it was working fine (according to this [post](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/1046.html)).

Is there a subtract operator for `List`s in Scala's standard library or do I need to cook one myself?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4) filterNot List(1,2).contains
res2: List[Int] = List(3, 4)
```

or

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4) diff List(1,2)
res3: List[Int] = List(3, 4)
```

Comment: Note that these two snippets aren't equivalent (try with `List(1,1,2,3,4)`)